# Why does Github sort capital letters over lowercase?

Tags: git, sorting, github

Looking in my Github repo, the naming convention goes something like this.

```
Repo
  Abc
  Sbc
  Zbc
  abc
```

Why does github have lowercase being sorted differently than uppercase?

Comment: what do you mean by `why` ??

Comment: @mrid I am curious about their reasoning, as to me it is not intuitive to have a lower case a below an uppercase Z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They names are probably sorted by their natural ASCII ordering. If you look at the ASCII table, the capital letters' values range from 65 ('A') to 90 ('Z'), while the lower case letters' values range from 97 ('a') to 122 ('z').

Comment: Is it common to sort by the ASCII ordering? On my computer's (mac/windows) they don't take uppercase into consideration (unless they lower it for sorting purposes)

Comment: @Childishforlife: sorting is a huge topic. Do you sort MacDuff before McAuliffe, or vice versa? [(Librarians have rules.)](http://www.cincinnatilibrary.org/info/shelvingtest.html) What's the correct sort order for "füss" (apparently, Hungarian for "run") vs "fuss"? Computers can be taught many rules; Windows and MacOS use sort-after-case-folding by default because they also case-fold by default, so that "HELLO" and "hello" are *the same* file. Linux `ls` sorts by your `$LC_COLLATE` setting. GitHub probably runs on Linux, but doesn't allow you to set a preferred LC_COLLATE.